# Making image disappear in a circular fashion

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawable, countdowntimer

I have an **image** of a circle. I want to display it to the user, at first.

In a `CountDownTimer`'s `onTick()` method, I want it to disappear smoothly, sector-by-sector, in a circular fashion. Below is an image that explains what I'd like to way better:

[image: frames]

*Gray areas are actually transparent.*

In the `onFinish()` of the `CountDownTimer` the image should disappear completely.

**1)** I guess this can be done using `Canvas.drawArc()`. I would have to calculate the angle, draw an arc and fill that sector of the circle image with transparent color, right?

```
new CountDownTimer(fullSpan, tick) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int angle = (fullSpan-millisUntilFinished) / fullSpan * 360;
        drawSector(angle);  //draw a transparent sector
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        drawSector(360);  //draw a transparent circle
    }
}.start();
```

**2)** I suspect there might be a better way of achieving this. I don't have any experience on Android `Canvas`. Can I have suggestions from the more experienced ones?

Comment: `fill that sector of the circle image with transparent color, right?` **wrong**. If you put a transparent color over any other, the result is that you will see the underlaying color (since transparent is invisible by definition). Instead, you will have to erase and redraw the filled (black in your illustration) shape.

Comment: Sure, you're right, my mistake. But since I get the image from drawable resources, I don't draw the circle. Is erasing it, reassigning the image to the imageView and filling the calculated sector with the background color -instead of transparency- the correct way, then?

Comment: One chance could be if the background was a **solid color**. Then you could **fake** transparency/erasing by using **the same color as the background** to cover the circle with an expanding arc (grey part of your illustration).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. if you'd like to write up an answer I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fill that sector of the circle image with transparent color, right?` **wrong**.
If you put a transparent color over any other, the result is that you will see the underlaying color (since transparent is invisible by definition).
Instead, you could erase and redraw the filled (black in your illustration) shape.

OR

One chance could be if the background was a **solid color**.
Then you could **fake** transparency/erasing by using the very same color as the background to cover up the circle with an expanding arc (the grey part in your illustration).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the way described in the accepted answer, but if anyone else needs a more detailed description, here it is:

The keyword here is [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html). As an intermediate Android developer, that's what I'd like to think of myself, I felt ashamed for not hearing the concept at all. Apparently, you can create layered drawables and display them inside an `ImageView`.

Here is the example:

```
Drawable [] layers = new Drawable[2];

ShapeDrawable d0 = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(270, angle));

Bitmap bm = ...
Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bm);

layers[0]=d1;
layers[1]=d0;

LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
iv_cdt.setBackground(composite);  //iv_cdt is an imageView
```

When you put this snippet inside a `CountDownTimer`, which was what I would have liked to do, you get an animation as shown in the question.